# How do I properly use the modulus operator in JAVA when it comes to very large numbers?

Tags: java, encryption, diffie-hellman, modulo

I am trying to get back the proper exponent, and while the example numbers (exampleA, exampleB, exampleP) all return what they should when running through the loop, plugging in long number(A, B, p) do not. Any way I can fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //g = 5//
        //let i run from 0 to p -1//
        //compute g^a mod p and see if it is A, if you find A, then a is the solution for A//
        //compute g^a mod p and see if it is B, if you find B, then a is the solution for B//
        long A = 1958258942L;
        long B = 670001116L;
        long p = 3267000013L;
        //example p to plug in for example a and example b//
        long exampleP = 23;
        //plugging this in should return 4//
        long exampleA = 4;
        //plugging this in should return 3//
        long exampleB = 10;
        int newNum;
        int a = 0;
        int g = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < (p - 1); i++) {
                a = i;
                newNum = powMod(g, a, exampleP);
                if (newNum == exampleB) break;
            }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    
    public static int powMod(int g, int exponent, long p) {
        int result = 1;

        while (exponent > 0)
        {
            // exponent is odd
            if (exponent % 2 == 1)
            {
                result = (int) ((result * g) % p);
            }

            // divide exponent in half
            exponent /= 2;

            // square base and take remainder 
            g = (int) ((g * g) % p);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Those numbers aren't very large at all, and aren't nearly large enough for secure Diffie-Hellman; they would work fine if you just use `long`. For numbers that actually are very large, you do _all_ computations correctly by using the `BigInteger` class which has a `modPow` method already coded -- but then bruteforce search will take longer than the universe will exist, making it not very useful, which is why DH actually is secure.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 then since I am already using long, shouldn't they work? Instead the program just continue to loop when I try to brute force the long numbers.

Comment: Both `result * g` and `g * g` will eventually likely cause integer overflow. The multiplies and `%` operations should be done as longs, and all `powerMod` parameters should be ints if you insist on avoiding BigInteger.